# bson.errors.InvalidBSON out of range

Tags: python, pymongo

I have a query from python to mongodb through pymongo.
Some records work for me, but on one record it stops working, it looks like there is a different date format, but how then it got into the find() :

```
from bson import ObjectId
import config_auth
from operator import itemgetter
from datetime import datetime
import pyodbc
import pymongo

mydb = config_auth.mydb

def load():
    temp_arr = []
    for item in mydb.questionaries.find({ 'created_at' : {"$gt": datetime(2019,10,30), "$lt": datetime(2019,10,31)}}):
        temp=[]
        temp.append(str(item['_id']))
        print(item['created_at'])
        temp_arr.append(tuple(temp))
```

After this i have this error:

`2019-10-30 15:36:09.920000
2019-10-30 15:36:02.344000
2019-10-30 15:36:02.344000
2019-10-30 15:33:47.360000
2019-10-30 15:33:47.360000
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/d.konoplya/Desktop/python/etl_finservice/questionaries.py", line 115, in <module>
    print(load())
  File "c:/Users/d.konoplya/Desktop/python/etl_finservice/questionaries.py", line 16, in load
    for item in mydb.questionaries.find({ 'created_at' : {"$gt": datetime(2019,10,30), "$lt": datetime(2019,10,31)}}):
  File "C:\Users\d.konoplya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pymongo\cursor.py", line 1156, in next
    if len(self.__data) or self._refresh():
  File "C:\Users\d.konoplya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pymongo\cursor.py", line 1093, in _refresh
    self.__send_message(g)
  File "C:\Users\d.konoplya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pymongo\cursor.py", line 955, in __send_message
    address=self.__address)
  File "C:\Users\d.konoplya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pymongo\mongo_client.py", line 1346, in _run_operation_with_response
    exhaust=exhaust)
  File "C:\Users\d.konoplya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pymongo\mongo_client.py", line 1464, in _retryable_read
    return func(session, server, sock_info, slave_ok)
  File "C:\Users\d.konoplya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pymongo\mongo_client.py", line 1340, in _cmd
    unpack_res)
  File "C:\Users\d.konoplya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pymongo\server.py", line 131, in run_operation_with_response
    user_fields=user_fields)
  File "C:\Users\d.konoplya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pymongo\cursor.py", line 1030, in _unpack_response
    legacy_response)
  File "C:\Users\d.konoplya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pymongo\message.py", line 1538, in unpack_response
    self.documents, codec_options, user_fields)
  File "C:\Users\d.konoplya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\bson\__init__.py", line 1098, in _decode_all_selective
bson.errors.InvalidBSON: year 0 is out of range`

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5db9849eb491a900016f913b"),
"updated_at" : ISODate("2019-10-30T13:10:29.320Z"),
"created_at" : ISODate("2019-10-30T12:39:58.277Z"),
"state" : "credit_issued",
"registred_in_1c_at" : ISODate("2019-10-30T13:33:19.504Z"),
"signer_id" : ObjectId("5d584ab05aeafd000191518a")
}
```

But each record has a date> 0. What could be the problem?

Thanks

Comment: Hi Daniel, I am having the same problem. Found something on that issue yet?

Answer (score 1):

I actually found it, this happens because MongoDB / BSON can represent dates outside the `datetime.datetime` range of Python.

> PyMongo decodes BSON datetime values to instances of Python’s
> datetime.datetime. Instances of datetime.datetime are limited to years
> between datetime.MINYEAR (usually 1) and datetime.MAXYEAR (usually
> 9999). Some MongoDB drivers (e.g. the PHP driver) can store BSON
> datetimes with year values far outside those supported by
> datetime.datetime.

Read more about this in the pymongo FAQ: https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq.html#why-do-i-get-overflowerror-decoding-dates-stored-by-another-language-s-driver

They suggest the following workarounds.

One is, to query for valid date ranges:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> coll = client.test.dates
>>> cur = coll.find({'dt': {'$gte': datetime.min, '$lte': datetime.max}})
```

The other is, to exclude the offending field from the results:

```
>>> cur = coll.find({}, projection={'dt': False})
```

Comment: I fixed it by just passing the data into a variable,an then get  I don't know how it affected, but it works. after that I already received data from a variable, and it helped. It looks like like cur = coll.find({...})

Answer (score 0):

If you did:

```
import datetime
```

This could cause problems; try

```
from datetime import datetime
```

It's a shame they couldn't have named them something different to prevent the bear traps that are so easy to fall in.

Comment: thanks, nothing change. other entries are uploaded, if i change segment. maybe this is due to something driver, which I can not understand. all record are simmilar and have date in one format

Comment: We'll need more than one line of code to fix the issue; please reproduce the error in full.

Comment: Can you add an example record from the collection using findOne() from the mongo shell; ideally one that the code is struggling with.

Comment: added record////

Comment: At the mongo shell (not pymongo) run `db.questionaries.find({'created_at': {'$lte': ISODate("0001-01-01T00:00:00Z")}})` Does it return any records?

Comment: no, zero records. i think it's some trouble with pymongo driver, or something like this. looks like trouble in  low-level architecture, maybe memory out or timeout, idk

Comment: Maybe. Are you on the latest versions of everything?

Comment: Yea, try do to this from another os and pc